# Debug: Feigin Client docker and Consul

Tags: java, spring, docker, registry, consul

I have Application with several microservices.
One of them uses another using Feign Client (REST-API client).
Also there is consul registry-server. All microservices are registred there.

In docker all works fine. microsercices can get access each other.
But I can't use feigin client from host machine (debug-mode).

For example: 
consul and several servcies are in docker, one of microserces is running on host.

Host microservice has error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connection timed out: connect executing GET http://dictionary-service/api/regions/4294967299
```

In fact host isn't correct.
There is configuration for service:

```
spring:

  application:
    name: dictionary-service

  cloud:
    consul:
      host: ${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}
      port: ${CONSUL_PORT:8500}
      config:
        enabled: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

I setted concrete host and port for using in docker and host networks, but it doesn't work.

How can I get access from host machine access using feigin client to this service?